# Tkinter-Hide or quit and get back a window

Tags: python, tkinter, hide, show

I'm trying to hide my window and show it back if it was open before.

For that, I'm using a global variable opened but this one is not behaving like I want.

For example, when I return from my window and go back my variable is False instead of the True I'm expecting.

I'm using Python 3.6 with Tkinter And down here is the code.

If someone, can explain to me why it´s behaving this way or what I did wrong, It will be nice of you. Thanks.

I know [this blog](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/26/tkinter-how-to-show-hide-a-window/) is showing a way to do that but I want to understand why this way is not working, thanks.

```
from tkinter import * 

def quit_window():  
   window.destroy()
   opened = False
   Main()



def return_main():  
    window.withdraw()
    opened = True
    print(opened)
    Main()

def launch():
    global opened, window
    print(opened)
    if opened == True:
        window.update()
        window.deiconify()
        main.destroy()
    else:
        window = Tk() 
        breturn = Button(window, text="Return", command=return_main).pack()
        bquit = Button(window, text="Quit", command=quit_window).pack() 
        main.destroy()
        window.mainloop()



def Main():  
    global main
    print(opened)
    main = Tk()  
    bopen = Button(main, text="Open", command=launch).pack() 
    main.mainloop()

opened = False 
Main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `global opened` in both `quit_window` and `return_main` functions. Because of that, when you click on the return button, your global variable `opened` is not changed, only the local one inside the `return_main` function.

In addition, I don't see the need to destroy `main` each time you display `window` since you go back and forth between the two. So my suggestion is to keep `main` and simply withdraw it when not needed. In this case, `window` will be a `Toplevel` of `main` and the code is:

```
from tkinter import * 

def quit_window():  
   global opened
   window.destroy()
   opened = False
   main.deiconify()

def return_main(): 
    global opened 
    window.withdraw()
    opened = True
    print(opened)
    main.deiconify()

def launch():
    global opened, window
    print(opened)
    main.withdraw()  # withdraw main instead of destroying it
    if opened == True:
        window.deiconify()
    else:
        window = Toplevel(main) 
        breturn = Button(window, text="Return", command=return_main).pack()
        bquit = Button(window, text="Quit", command=quit_window).pack()   

main = Tk()  
bopen = Button(main, text="Open", command=launch).pack() 
opened = False 
main.mainloop()  # call mainloop only for main
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought I have to define just one time the global variable.